# T-SQL min function with alias for column header

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, alias

If I do the following in SSMS 2008 r2, using T-SQL:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [col1] 
FROM [table1] AS ourResult
```

The alias column header `ourResult` works as expected.

However, if I do the very similar:

```
SELECT MIN([Date]) 
FROM [table1] AS min_date1
```

the alias for the column header does not work and instead there is:

```
(No column name)
```

Is there a fix for this somewhat simple situation?

Comment: What interface shows "ourResult" as the column header? Because that's a table alias, not a column alias. `col1` is what should show as the column alias. If you want to alias an expression, you say `expression AS alias`, not `expression FROM table AS alias`. (To avoid confusion, you might even consider the proprietary column aliasing I prefer, which is `alias = expression`. [Here's why](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query

```
SELECT TOP 1 [col1] 
FROM [table1] AS ourResult
```

will return    **col1** as the columnheader

but this query

```
SELECT MIN([Date]) 
FROM [table1] AS min_date
```

will return **(No column name)** because you wrap the actual column with a function therefore you need a new name or keep the same one by doing this

```
SELECT MIN([Date]) as minDate
FROM [table1] AS min_date
```

the **From clause with "as" is the alias for the table and not the column**.